# How can an Ad Network track CPI without putting SDK in advertised app?

Tags: android, admob

Let's say an advertiser give you an apk to advertise with CPI.

How can an Ad Network track CPI if the advertised apk doesn't include SDK to track install and report to our server?

We will install the apk directly i.e. no google playstore involved.

Comment: The APK must communicate with the Ad Network either via an Ad SDK or via JavaScript in a WebView (similar to online ads).

Comment: @MorrisonChang, thanks. That's what I thought so. So, maybe we can wrap the original apk with our tracker and then install original apk from our tracker app? That would require user to give two permissions though. What do you think?

Comment: If you are doing your own app installer (like Amazon) that is outside of the Google Play Store - you can manage install metrics however you like as the app installer is the one downloading and prompting the user to install the client app. Perhaps the question needs more clarification.

Comment: I see. I do not have my own installer also.